# How to avoid java.lang OutOfMemory error in Jmeter?

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I have been trying to run 50 users in `Jmeter`, but I see `Java.Lang OutOfMemory` error in the command prompt once the number of users crosses 35. My machine has a physical memory of 16GB and in-spite of increasing the heap size to 8GB(8192m) in the jmeter.bat file, I still happen to see the same error. I have also disabled the listeners to reduce the memory consumption as well and I used the below heap commands to increase its size.

```
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=8192m
```

I also used a few more alternative commands to increase the heap size which are:

```
set HEAP="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -X:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m" && jmeter.bat

HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx4096m"
```

But I happen a see another error stating

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
errorlevel=1
```

Can anybody help me in resolving this issue for running a test with 50 users successfully?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have 64-bit Java installation, you won't be able to allocate more than [2 gigabytes to 32-bit JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_GB_limit)

   [image]
2. Make sure to use proper syntax as you made a typo and it doesn't looks like you know what you're really doing (setting too high [metaspace size](http://techidiocy.com/metaspace-java8/) will rather cause the problems than fix them):

   [image]
3. [OutOfMemoryError Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) can have many faces, it's not necessarily connected with insufficient heap, read the stacktrace and eventual .[hprof file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html) more attentively
4. Make sure to follow recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article